# Por que usar colchetes duplos no Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, merge

Dados os seguinte *Dataframes*:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 1], [4, 5, 2], [1, 2 , 3]],
     columns=['coluna1', 'coluna2','id'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 7, 1], [4, 'a', 2], [1, 'abc', 3]],
     columns=['coluna3','coluna4', 'id'])
```

Eu quero fazer um merge entre eles porém só trazendo a **coluna3** do **df2**

Caso eu use:

```
df = df.merge(df2['coluna3','id'], on='id', how='left')
```

Eu recebo o seguinte erro:

> > KeyError: ('coluna3', 'id')

Mas se ao invés de usar somente um colchete ( [] ) para selecionar as colunas que eu desejo, eu usar dois ( [[]] ), funciona normalmente, por que isso??

```
df = df.merge(df2[['coluna3','id']], on='id', how='left')
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na prática, são dois operadores iguais e são equivalentes ao método `__getitem__`, segundo a documentação do pandas que você pode ver [aqui](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html).

Fica mais fácil entender essa equivalência observando um exemplo. Para replicar o resultado usando `[]` com o `__getitem__` basta fazer:

```
df.__getitem__('coluna1')
```

que retorna:

```
0    1
1    4
2    1
```

Note que, como é uma função, se você usar `coluna1, coluna2` o python vai entender que se tratam de dois argumentos, mas a função espera um só. Por isso que fazendo assim você terá um erro dado por `__getitem__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given` ( o primeiro argumento é *self*, o próprio dataframe).

Contudo, apesar da função `_getitem_` não aceitar mais de uma string além do dataframe, ela aceita uma lista de strings como único argumento, como você pode ver rodando `df.__getitem__(['coluna1','coluna2'])`

Enfim, é basicamente essa a explicação. É como se não existisse o operador `[]`, ele e só um símbolo que replica o comportamento de uma função que aceita apenas um argumento.

Leia sobre a `__getitem__` [aqui](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__)